# Why isn't wmctrl working?

Tags: wmctrl

I am on Ubuntu 14.04. I installed wmctrl using `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`.

Now in the terminal when I try `wmctrl -s 0` or `wmctrl -s 1` nothing happens. I don't even get any error.

Comment: Do `wmctrl -d `, check how many desktops you have

Comment: Oh just one. And it is listed with an asterix. How to add more?

Comment: If you're using Unity, you may have just the *one* desktop (aka workspace). That desktop is subdivided into viewports. Please read @Jacob Vlijm's answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/742407/248158

Comment: how many screen you have connected? if you have two screen this migth help you:
http://superuser.com/questions/264281/wmctrl-says-i-have-one-workspace-when-i-actually-have-four