# Is it possible to cycle through workspaces in Unity (14.04+)?

Tags: 14.04, unity, workspaces, wmctrl, viewports

I have configured my keyboard shortcuts so that Alt + left takes me to the work space left, and Alt + right takes me to the work space to the right, but I would rather have one set of keys to cycle. Ideally, something like

```
workspace 1 + Alt + tab ---> worskspace 2
workspace 2 + Alt + tab ---> worskspace 3
workspace 3 + Alt + tab ---> worskspace 4
workspace 4 + Alt + tab ---> worskspace 1
```

The problem is the last line. I don't see any way to go from work space 4 back to work space 1. How to move to the right modulo 4 ?

Comment: Well, by default there already exists a shortcut - Ctrl + Alt + Arrow Keys. If you configure 2x3 workspace, for example, you'd use those to move around in a grid

Comment: Hi uhuola, posted my answer. Please let me know if you manage.

Answer (score 3):

#### Cycle through your viewports

With a small script, it is very well possible to browse through the workspaces (actually viewports):

- *forward*:

  [image]

  (If the last viewport is reached, the script moves to the first one)
- ...or *backward*:

  [image]

  (If the first viewport is reached, the script moves to the last one)

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

move = sys.argv[1]

# get the needed info from wmctrl -d
wsdata = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-d"]).decode("utf-8").split()
# retrieve total size of workspace
ws = [int(n) for n in wsdata[3].split("x")]
# panel/launcher height/width
pans = [int(n) for n in wsdata[7].split(",")]
# work area
wa = [int(n) for n in wsdata[8].split("x")]
# x/y resolution
res_h = pans[0]+wa[0]; res_v = pans[1]+wa[1]
# current position in the spanning workspace
VP = [int(n) for n in wsdata[5].split(",")]

def last_h():
    # test if we are on the last viewport horizontally
    return VP[0]+res_h == ws[0]

def first_h():
    # test if we are on the first viewport horizontally
    return VP[0] == 0

def last_v():
    # test if we are on the last viewport vertically
    return VP[1]+res_v == ws[1]

def first_v():
    # test if we are on the first viewport vertically
    return VP[1] == 0

if move == "next":
    if last_h() == False:
        command = str(VP[0]+res_h)+","+str(VP[1])
    elif last_v() == True:
        command = "0,0"
    else:
        command = "0,"+str(VP[1]+res_v)

if move == "prev":
    if first_h() == False:
        command = str(VP[0]-res_h)+","+str(VP[1])
    elif first_v() == True:
        command = str(ws[0]-res_h)+","+str(ws[1]-res_v)
    else:
        command = str(ws[0]-res_h)+","+str(VP[1]-res_v)

subprocess.Popen(["wmctrl", "-o", command])
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs [wmctrl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `through_viewports.py`
3. Add two commands to two different shortcut keys:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/through_viewports.py next
   ```

   to go to the next viewport, and:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/through_viewports.py prev
   ```

   to go to the previous viewport

   Open System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts. Click the `+` and add both commands to shortcuts you like.

***That's it*** The script detects how your viewports are set up and cycles through them.

#### How it works, the concept

In Unity, viewports are arranged in one big matrix, which all together makes the single *workspace*, the Unity desktop exists of.

Using the command:

```
wmctrl -d
```

in the output, we can read all information we need to find out where we currently are in the matrix.

```
0  * DG: 5120x2400  VP: 0,0  WA: 65,24 1215x776  N/A
```

- `5120x2400` is the total size of all viewports (matrix)
- `0,0` is the x/y position of the current viewport in the matrix (top left, pixels)
- from `WA: 65,24 1215x776` we can derive the screen's resolution (`65,24` are the width/height of the Launcher/panel, `1215x776` is the remaining area)

Once we have the correct information, the script calculates the target position in the matrix and sets it with the command:

```
wmctrl -o x,y
```

Comment: @DKBose isn't that what I wrote in the answer? "*In Unity, viewports are arranged in one big matrix, which all together makes the single workspace, the Unity desktop exists of*" Unity indeed has only one workspace by definition.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is really complete and clear!
I just wanted to know: is it important the location where I put the file "through_viewports.py"?
Thank you,
Cloé

Comment: I would just store it locally unless you'd use it for all users.

Answer (score 2):

In 12.04 I had solved this problem by editing a key with gconf-editor, but didn't have that same key in 16.04 so here's what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

which installs a GUI advanced-settings utility, then

```
ccsm
```

which launches it. And then I went to *Desktop Wall > Viewport Switching > Allow Wrap-Around* and checked the box.